# The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing an application on node.js
I need to insert a Static Google Map.
The code looks like this

```
  .panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      h2.panel-title On the map
    .panel-body
      img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{location.coords.lat},#{location.coords.lng}&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=false&markers=#{location.coords.lat},#{location.coords.lng}&scale=2&key=AIzaSyDt0D6sy4v8BZFVJiAea93aiR63E-GpBL8")
```

Controller, from where information about coordinates is taken

```
res.render('location-info', {
    title: 'empty',
    pageHeader: {title: 'empty'},
    sidebar: {
        context: 'empty',
        callToAction: 'empty.'
    },
    location: {
        name: 'empty',
        address: 'empty',
        rating: 5,
        facilities: ['empty'],
        coords: {lat: 55.752813, lng: 37.791908},
        openingTimes: [{
            days: 'empty',
            opening: '19:00',
            closing: '01:00',
            closet: false
        },{
```

[How it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VikzQ.jpg)
When im try to copy someone else's code, everything works fine. Help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Template literals use `$`, eg `${varNameHere}` - not `#{location.coords.lat}`.

Try:

`src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${location.coords.lat},${location.coords.lng}&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=false&markers=${location.coords.lat},${location.coords.lng}&scale=2&key=AIzaSyDt0D6sy4v8BZFVJiAea93aiR63E-GpBL8"`

Comment: Thank you! All work with this: img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + location.coords.lat + ',' + location.coords.lng + '+&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=false&markers=' + location.coords.lat + ',' + location.coords.lng + '&scale=2')

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error messages from Google Map [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages).

In your case, the size parameter is not within the expected range of numeric values, or is missing from the request.